# What am I missing about the paradox between relativity and quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, relativity

Please help me understand what the paradox or disconnect is between quantum mechanics and general relativity. With my very simple understanding of each, there appears to be harmony to me.

Specifically:
Through classical physics, we know that waves are energy.
Thought quantum field theory, we know matter is made of waves. 
Through Einstein, we know energy equals mass (proportionately)
Through relativity, we know matter has mass and curves spacetime

Therefore, all matter is wave energy and these waves curve spacetime

I guess it’s metaphorically like waves in the ocean that curve the surface of the ocean.

This all seems to fit together to me, but I’m clearly missing something (a lot), to understand why this is one of the greatest unsolved problems in physics.

Thank you for explaining it to an amateur like me.

Comment: *Through classical physics, we know that waves are energy* Can you cite your source on this? I must have missed this in my physics education.

Comment: Even if this was true, how have you solved the unification of GR and QM? Saying "matter is wave energy that curves space time" certainly doesn't solve anything.

Comment: An example of a current puzzle is: When matter and radiation fall into a black hole and hit the singularity, what happens to their quantum state? We know that General Relativity says that black holes, once they settle down, have only three parameters. So what happens to all the other quantum information? We need a quantum description of a black hole to answer this.

Comment: Another example: If you collide two electrons at high energy, there should be some probability that they create a black hole. How do we calculate the probability that this happens, correct to all orders of perturbation theory? How do we include non-perturbative effects? You need a theory of quantum gravity for this.